# Sequentially rename duplicate value in character variable before reshaping it with dcast

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I'm **scraping** cars information from a website and I'm getting not constant and not so clean data from it. I'm trying to clean and arrange this data into a data frame.

For example:

```
dd <- data.frame(measure = c("wheel", "wheel", "length", "width", "wheel", "width"), value = 1:6, model = "a", stringsAsFactors = F)
dd
  measure value model
1   wheel     1     a
2   wheel     2     a
3  length     3     a
4   width     4     a
5   wheel     5     a
6   width     6     a
```

It this example, I have 3 values of `wheel` and 2 of `width`.  In my real data, it's not always the same thing that is repeated, it may or may not have repetition and it could be repeated more than once.

I need to reshape this table to have one line per `model`, however I don't want to aggregate the `value` that have a common `measure`.  Precisely, I would want the table to become:

```
  model length wheel wheel1 wheel2 width width1
1     a      3     1      2      5     4      6
```

This was obtained using `dcast` on manually modified data:

```
library(reshape2)    
res <- data.frame(measure = c("wheel", "wheel1", "length", "width", "wheel2", "width1"), value = 1:6, model = "a", stringsAsFactors = F)
dcast(res, model ~ measure)
```

I need either a way to modify `dcast` so it doesn't aggregate the `measure` or automatically modify `dd` so it becomes `res`.

I've tried something ugly and not exactly what I needed:

```
dd[duplicated(dd$measure), "measure"] <- paste0(dd[duplicated(dd$measure), "measure"] , 1:3)
dd
  measure value model
1   wheel     1     a
2  wheel1     2     a
3  length     3     a
4   width     4     a
5  wheel2     5     a
6  width3     6     a
```

This code isn't working because `width` get the index `3` and not `2`.  Also, this would not adjust to another table like:

```
dd2 <- data.frame(measure = c("wheel", "wheel", "length", "width", "wheel"), value = 1:5, model = "a", stringsAsFactors = F)
dd2[duplicated(dd2$measure), "measure"] <- paste0(dd2[duplicated(dd2$measure), "measure"] , 1:3)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, duplicated(dd2$measure), "measure",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
```

Anyway, how could I modify my variable `measure` dynamically so all the words are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `dplyr::mutate` as below:

```
dd <- dd %>%
  group_by(model, measure) %>%
  mutate(measure2 = paste0(measure, ifelse(row_number() > 1, row_number() - 1, ""))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(measure = measure2) %>%
  select(measure, model, value)
dd
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  measure model value
  <chr>   <chr> <int>
1 wheel   a         1
2 wheel1  a         2
3 length  a         3
4 width   a         4
5 wheel2  a         5
6 width1  a         6
```

Comment: I had tried (and failed) with `mutate`.  Your use of `group_by` is smart.  Works perfect!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
dd %>%
 arrange(model, measure) %>%
 group_by(model, measure) %>%
 mutate(var = paste(measure, seq_along(measure), sep = "_")) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-measure) %>%
 spread(var, value)

  model length_1 wheel_1 wheel_2 wheel_3 width_1 width_2
  <chr>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 a            3       1       2       5       4       6
```

Answer (score 1):

`make.unique` does just that:

```
dd$measure <- make.unique(dd$measure,sep = "")  
dd            
#    measure value model
# 1   wheel     1     a
# 2  wheel1     2     a
# 3  length     3     a
# 4   width     4     a
# 5  wheel2     5     a
# 6  width1     6     a
```

Comment: At some point reading (or skimming through) the full doc of base and utils functions is a good thing to do, I did it a couple times and don't regret the time investment, it doesn't take as long as one may think and there's a few hidden gems here and there :).

Answer (score 0):

You also could renumber the values with a `sapply`

```
sapply(unique(dd$measure), function(x) {
  z <- dd$measure[dd$measure %in% x]
  if (length(z) > 1)
  dd$measure[dd$measure %in% x] <<- paste0(z, ".", seq(length(z)))
})
```

and use `reshape` after.

```
reshape(dd, direction="wide", timevar="measure", idvar="model")
#   model value.wheel.1 value.wheel.2 value.length value.width.1 value.wheel.3 value.width.2
# 1     a             1             2            3             4             5             6
```

***Data***

```
dd <- structure(list(measure = c("wheel", "wheel", "length", "width", "wheel", "width"), 
                     value = 1:6, model = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```